# What are the pros and cons about the ways to import an alternative Prelude?

Tags: haskell

There are quite a few alternatives that (subjectively) improve on the standard Haskell Prelude. When developing applications it makes sense to use them, but how to best tell your compiler that?

My ideas:

```
import qualified Prelude
import MyPrelude
```

But then HLint complains that importing Prelude qualified is redundant.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
import MyPrelude
```

This seems to work but is rather verbose.

```
Some kind of global LANGUAGE pragma in the cabal file
```

Are there other ways? Is there a generally agreed on standard?

Comment: I don't see any such complaint from HLint with `hlint-1.9.16`. I think those first two are fine and I've also seen `import Prelude ()` suggested. I'm more skeptical about a global pragma because it means the source file doesn't say clearly what it imports.

Comment: Voting to close as "opinion-based": "best way" is ambiguous and too open to interpretation to encourage helpful answers. It is generally considered good form to ask for "a way" instead; and since you have a way already, then you will need to say what you don't like about that way.

Comment: Also, be aware that there are, coming very soon, some major changes in GHC's Prelude; but it's controversial.  GHC 7.10, whose release is imminent (they're on RC2), was slated to change from a `List` based Prelude, to a more generalized Prelude, and the implementors apparently thought they had buy-in from the Haskell community, but now that change is being reconsidered. [https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Prelude710](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Prelude710)

Comment: @DanielWagner I should have asked about the pros and cons, will change my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to import a distinct prelude, then not importing the standard prelude is correct, and hence

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
import MyPrelude
```

is the standard way.